# Голосовой набор как ok google

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-speech-recognition

Есть ли возможность использовать голосовой набора используя модуль или плагин ok google (только русский язык) для своего сайта где после автоматический набора текста, получил на свой переменный для своих задач.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Фраза _где после автоматический набора текста, получил на свой переменный для своих задач_ непонятна.

Comment: Например, после того как ты говорил, происходит автоматический набор текста (с голос на текст) а потом будет мой button после клика сверяет не с мой базой данных. Вообщем нужна только функционал набора с голоса на текст

Comment: @Regent он пытается сказать, что ему нужно "Распознавание Речи", или другими словами - голосовой набор текста.

`MuhammadYakubov` вот что Вам нужно - `http://voiceassistant.mobi`

Comment: Да.Но не мобильный. Есть ли какой-нибудь плагин или API от google или где-то еще для того чтобы только мог использовать функционал Распознавание речи а далее у меня есть своя база где хранятся тексты где сверят текст и делает какой нибудь действия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вы и попросили, нашел для Вас не мобильный API - Web Speech API с подробной документацией на английском языке от Google.

[Web Speech API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API)

все хорошо и понятно расписано.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Я тоже самое нашел. https://www.google.ru/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html